# How do I find the rate of a kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any approach to find by what rate kafka consumer is consuming messages?
Like 5000 messages/second

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The KafkaConsumer client exposes a number of metrics including the message rate.

The metric is named `kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id="{client-id}"` and the attribute for message rate is `records-consumed-rate`.

Check the Consumer metrics list in the [Kafka docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#new_consumer_fetch_monitoring).

The metrics are exposed via JMX, you can fire `jconsole` to quickly access them. The Consumer also allows to access them directly via the [metrics()](http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#metrics--) method

Comment: But I am not using confluent kafka.
So is it possible without confluent?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Confluent. Kafka is an Apache project, everything on kafka.apache.org is part of the open source project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So how can I use this API to get consumer rate?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added methods to access the metrics

Comment: Yes Sir ..I got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MickaelMaison This was very helpful. Thanks!!